# Flutter Calculate Number of nights between two given date and time

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart

Hi guys i want to calculate number of nights between two given date and times in flutter

for example

From date and time
"28-12-2021 16:00:00"

To date and time
"04-01-2022 23:59:00"

can any one help to achieve this in better way

Note:-

3hour consider as **1/4 night** in between (6pm to 6am)

6hour consider as **1/2 night** in between (6pm to 6am)

9hour consider as **1/3 night** in between (6pm to 6am)

12 hour consider as **1 night** (6pm to 6am)

Comment: Could you clarify your criteria?  Would 6:01 PM to 12:01 AM be considered 1/2 night?  What about 9 PM to 3 AM?  Is your definition of "1 night" to be a period whose intersection with the interval [6 PM, 6 AM] is strictly greater than 6 hours?

Comment: criteria
its simple 
3hour consider as 1/4 night
6hour consider as 1/2 night
9hour consider as 1/3 night
12 hour consider as 1 night (6pm to 6am)

Comment: You say that 12 hours is considered as "1 night", but originally you said that "06:00 pm to 12:01 am as 1 night".  Also, 9 is not 1/3 of 12...

Comment: @jamesdlin i have to calculate the number of nights(6:00pm - 6:00am) between the two given dates. also nights splitter into 4 the details updated in question.

So i have to return the nights like. 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1, 1.25 etc. . , its based on how may day the customer selected from start date

Comment: Yes, I just wanted you to be consistent in what you were asking for since you specified conflicting requirements.  You also should be aware that if a locale observes Daylight Saving Time, a local time period from 6 PM to 6 AM could be 11 hours or 13 hours, which could complicate things.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of hours between two date

```
final hourNumber = secondDate.difference(firstDate).inHours;
```

Comment: But my question is how to calculate or get the number of nights